# Rename all the file names that match a pattern in linux

Tags: regex, linux

How to change all the file names in a directory that match `A_B_[any number c]_[any number d].R` to `A_B_[number c]_M_[number d].R` in linux? I.e., insert the 'M' in these matched file names.

There are also files named `A_B_[any number]_D_[any number].R` in this directory and these files should not be affected.

I tried   `rename 's/(\d+)_(\d+)/$1_M_$2/' *` , but it does not work.

Comment: You can do this recursively using `find` and `sed` with a regular expression.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do it?

Comment: I presume `"any number c"` is a placeholder for the string representation of a number, say, a positive integer, but the fact you later shorten that to `"number c"` may be confusing. Is `"A_B_[123]_[456]"` or `"A_B_123_456"` an example of such a string? Are you only concerned with strings that begin `"A_B_"` or are `"A"` and `"B"` placeholders as well, so the string might be `"C_D_[123]_[456]"`? Work on being more precise. It's a prerequisite to becoming a good coder.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```bash
rename -n 's/^A_B_(\d+)_(\d+)\.R/A_B_$1_M_$2.R/' A_B_*.R
```

explanation:

- [rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename) is a common utility on linux.
- the expression `'s/^A_B_(\d+)_(\d+)\.R/A_B_$1_M_$2.R/'` indicates search and replace:

  - `^` means beginning of filename
  - `A_B_` matches those literal characters after beginning of line
  - `(\d+)` matches any number of digits and captures the result as `$1`
  - `_` matches a literal underscore
  - `(\d+)` captures the next group of digits into `$2`
  - `/A_B_$1_M_$2.R/` is the replacement expression that makes use of capture groups and injects an "M" in the middle.
  - `A_B_*.R` is a glob pattern indicating what files to input into rename
  - a file of the pattern `A_B_[any number]_D_[any number].R` will be skipped because it does not match the above regex.

Bonus points:

To make absolutely sure you skip over certain files, you could use [bash extended globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

rename -n 's/^A_B_(\d+)_(\d+)\.R/A_B_$1_M_$2.R/' A_B_+([0-9])_+([0-9]).R
```